# Jira + Liferay integration

Tags: oauth, liferay, jira, opensocial, liferay-6

I added a Jira (4.2) gadget onto Liferay (6.1 b4) page. Set up the consumer and public keys in Jira Adminstrator's area for Liferay. Specified the same ones in OpenSocial portlet. I've tried on localhost only but anytime I get the following error:

{"oauthError":"UNKNOWN_PROBLEM","body":"","oauthErrorText":"Unable to retrieve consumer key\n\n==== Original request:\nGET /rest/gadget/1.0/currentUser?cacheBuster=1323789929397\n\nHost: 127.0.0.1:9080\nX-Shindig-AuthType: oauth\nX-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1\nX-shindig-dos: on\n\n\n====","DataHash":"qgeopmcf02p09qc016cepu22fo","rc":403}

Has anyone ever succeded in Liferay + Jira integration with OAuth?

Comment: I've asked the Liferay developer that worked on this if he knows of any issues! Hopefully we'll have an answer soon.

Answer (score 4):

There was a small bug in Liferay's OpenSocial portlet that prevented JIRA gadgets from working. I've submitted a pull request for the fix here: [link](https://github.com/dejuknow/liferay-plugins/commit/373a5580f8066a4d67c77eb8317155397a7316ab), [ticket](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-24088?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel). You can apply the patch if you want to get it working immediately.

Also, make sure you've taken all these steps to get JIRA gadgets working on Liferay. (Note: I've only tested with JIRA 4.4, but hopefully it's similar enough to 4.2).

On Liferay:

1. Place your private key in {myportal}/data/opensocial/rsaSigningKey.pem. This is the path and file name the OpenSocial portlet expects. The file name is settable in portlet.properties (use portlet-ext.properties if you want to change the values).
2. After publishing the JIRA gadget in the Control Panel, go to Manage OAuth, select RSA_PRIVATE for the key type, and make up a consumer key (like: "www.myjira.com").

On JIRA:

1. Create an Application Link for your Liferay portal instance.
2. Click "Configure" for the new Application Link and go to "Incoming Authentication". Enter the same consumer key as above (like "www.myjira.com") and the text for your public key (paired to rsaSigningKey.pem).

You should now be able to add JIRA gadgets to Liferay.

Comment: Btw, is it supposed to work with Jira via SSL? It seems no OAuth response from Jira in such case.

Comment: Is there any tutorial around? How do you get the pem file in the first place?

Comment: You can create the keys using tools like openssl. Lots of information here on stackoverflow and elsewhere on creating asymmetric key pairs.

Comment: This post helped my to create the correct pem file: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/45037/how-do-you-configure-jira-to-use-oauth-with-a-generic-application-specifically-jenkins